# Ionic framework not loading ng-model variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks, angular-ngmodel

I'm building an Ionic app and I have an issue reading the value of a `ng-model`.

**HTML**:

```
<select id="objetivos"  
        class="form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" 
        ng-model="objetivosSelec" 
        ng-options="objetivo.value for objetivo in objetivos | filter: filtroServicio | orderBy: 'value' | unique: 'value'" 
        ng-change="">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

**Controller**:

```
.controller('TecnicasCtrl', function($scope, Tecnicas, Servicios,Objetivos,Indicaciones,Contraindicaciones) {
    ...  
    $scope.limpiarFiltro = function() {
        alert($scope.objetivosSelec);
    }  
    ...
})
```

I just want to show on an alert the selected value of the select but nothing is displayed. If I add `.val()` then a JavaScript error is arised:

```
*Error: $scope.objetivosSelec is undefined*
```

I'm reading the Angular and Ionic doc and everything seems ok.

Has anyone an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I finally got it!!

**HTML:**

```
ng-model="$parent.servicioSelec"
```

I needed to use $parent in my ng-model items to read them from the controller.

This link was very useful to solve this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method is to always use an object as the model and not a single value. This error happens because angular creates nested scopes for the child directives in you view and the way prototypal inheritance works. Please refer http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html